# Value of type 'User' has no subscripts

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, user-interface, nsobject

I am trying to create a UITableView on my IOS app that displays a list of all the app's registered users from Firebase and includes a UISearchBar to search through them. I am very new to this and unfortunately this code is giving me the following error: "Value of type 'User' has no subscripts" on the line of code "let user = users[indexPath.row]"

There is an NSObject User class in another file that defines name and email as String?

These are the variables:

```
var searchActive : Bool!
var userList = [User]()
var filterUsers = [User]()
private var users = User()
private var hasFetched = false
```

Here is the search bar function I was using that is giving me the error:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    filterUsers = userList.filter({ (text) -> Bool in

        let temp: NSString = text.name! as NSString
        let range = temp.range(of: searchText, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)
        return range.location != NSNotFound

    })

    if(filterUsers.count == 0){
        searchActive = false;
    } else {
        searchActive = true;
    }
   //refreshTable()
    
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if(searchActive) {
            return filterUsers.count
        }
        return userList.count;
    }

   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        if let user = userList[indexPath.row] as? [String : AnyObject] {
        }
    
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")! as UITableViewCell;
        let user = users[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = user.name
        cell.textLabel?.text = user.name
        

        return cell;
    }
```

}
}

Comment: You defined `users` as an object. Hence you will never be able to subscript as an array.

Answer (score 2):

Modify this:

```
let user = users[indexPath.row]
```

To this:

```
let user = searchActive ? filterUsers[indexPath.row] : userList[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: Thank you for the help but I still don't understand... I changed the declaration for user as you told me to and tried to use user instead of userList for this but see the same warning. the type User is an NSObject class with two variables. Should I change it from an NSObject for this to work? I am just trying to display users from firebase. Thank you for the help I am very new to this